# query issue in postgres

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I am using the following code snippet in a Node.js application to attempt to query a (local) postgres database:

```
   var conString = "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase";
   var client = new pg.Client(conString);

    client.connect(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
      }
      client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $1 AND cred = $2", [String(req.body.usr), String(req.body.pword)], function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
          return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
         if (typeof result.rows[0] === "undefined") {
         console.log("No user/password determined in DB for login attempt");
         } else {

         }  //user/password is 'undefined' (NOT found in database)...OR NOT... 

        client.end();
      });
    });
```

I am receiving an error when the query runs...I believe the problem may possibly be the number of parameters in my query call...?  If that is the case (or it is some other syntax problem) could anybody be so kind to inform how I should change the code to perform the query correctly...?

I simply need to take 2 (user-supplied) results from a form (req.body.usr and req.body.pword) and compare them to the database table 'users' to determine if the credentials are correct.  I already believe the database connection works properly.  Any advice greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Comment: does your `req.body` contain `usr` or `pword`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $1 AND cred = $2", [String(req.body.usr), String(req.body.pword)], function(err, result) {...
```

to:

```
const query = {
    text: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $1 AND cred = $2", 
    values: [String(req.body.usr), String(req.body.pword)]
};
client.query(query, function(err, result) {
```

Read more: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried however that does not seem to be the problem.  My error message is "error running query { error: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0".  So it seems to be in the syntax of the query but I am at a loss as how to correct it...never tried this before.